# cmake is not possible to find mysql libraries when I setup mydumper

Tags: mysql, cmake

Before I setup mydumper, my server is running with mysqld 5.6

I download mydumper from

`https://launchpad.net/mydumper/0.6/0.6.2/+download/mydumper-0.6.2.tar.gz`

I install all dependencies that mydumper need:

```
yum install cmake pcre-devel glib2-devel zlib-devel gcc gcc-c++ mysql-devel openssl-devel
```

When I run cmake . I see some errors:

```
-- Using mysql-config: /usr/bin/mysql_config
-- MySQL not found.

CMake Warning at docs/CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  Unable to find Sphinx documentation generator


-- ------------------------------------------------
-- MYSQL_CONFIG = /usr/bin/mysql_config
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /usr/local
-- BUILD_DOCS = ON
-- WITH_BINLOG = OFF
-- RUN_CPPCHECK = OFF
-- Change a values with: cmake -D<Variable>=<Value>
-- ------------------------------------------------
-- 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
MYSQL_LIBRARIES_dl
    linked by target "mydumper" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
    linked by target "myloader" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
MYSQL_LIBRARIES_m
    linked by target "mydumper" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
    linked by target "myloader" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
MYSQL_LIBRARIES_mysqlclient
    linked by target "mydumper" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
    linked by target "myloader" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
MYSQL_LIBRARIES_pthread
    linked by target "mydumper" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
    linked by target "myloader" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
MYSQL_LIBRARIES_rt
    linked by target "mydumper" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2
    linked by target "myloader" in directory /root/mydumper-0.6.2

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/mydumper-0.6.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/mydumper-0.6.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I also read mydumper-0.6.2/cmake/modules/FindMySQL.cmake and then make some modification:

I add /usr/lib64/mysql in find_library function but it is not use.

There is no constraint I must use mydumper. Just I have little curiosity and want to try it.

How do I resolve this problem of cmake ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: No one want to answer :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to remove the directory of decompressed mydumper, then decompress the "mydumper-0.6.2.tar.gz" again, and cmake it, you'll find it works well.

Here is my operation:

```
rm -rf mydumper-0.6.2
tar -zxvf mydumper-0.6.2.tar.gz
cd mydumper-0.6.2
cmake .
make
make install
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Confirmed that the unzipped file can be in a corrupt state. This happened for me because I attempted to make once without all of the required dependencies installed. After installing the dependencies, I continued to hit this error. Removing this dir and downloading again fixed the state issue.

Comment: Just saved my day! 
I tried to run cmake before installing all dependencies. Looks like it corrupted something